# Postgres Convert Rows to Columns based on a Common field Using Crosstab

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgresql-10

I have query `select dist_name::text,service_name::text,status,count from mpr_application_status` that returns

```
+---------------+--------------+----------------+-------+
| District Name | Service Name | Current Status | Count |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+-------+
| Dehradun      |          143 | APPROVED       |     1 |
| Dehradun      |         143  | PENDING        |     2 |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+-------+
```

I want to return a result set like this  where we are converting rows into column based on the district name

```
+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| District Name | Service Name | ApprovedCount | Rejected Count | Pending  Count | Total Count |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
| Dehradun      |          143 |             1 |              0 |              2 |           3 |
+---------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+-------------+
```

I have tried using crosstab function to return this desired table

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'select dist_name::text,service_name::text,count from mpr_application_status ORDER BY 1,2') 
   AS ct ("District Name" text, "Service Name" text,"Approved Count" bigint,"Pending Count" bigint, "Reject Count" bigint);
```

But encountering errors

```
ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
SQL state: 42601
```

Is there any way I can achieve this result on the Database end ?
I am using postgresql 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this by using `SUM` and `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT dist_name::text,service_name::text
,SUM(case when status = 'APPROVED' then count else 0 end) approved_count
,SUM(case when status = 'REJECTED' then count else 0 end) rejected_count
,SUM(case when status = 'PENDING' then count else 0 end) pending_count
,SUM(count) as total_count
FROM mpr_application_status
GROUP BY dist_name,service_name
```

Comment: Alternatively: `count(*) filter (where status = 'APPROVED') as approved_count`

Answer (score 1):

The format of `crosstab()` you are using will not comply with your desired output. You should write it like below:

```
SELECT 
"District Name",
"Service Name",
coalesce("Approved Count",0),
coalesce("Pending Count",0),
coalesce("Reject Count",0),
coalesce("Approved Count",0)+coalesce("Pending Count",0)+coalesce("Reject Count",0) "Total"
FROM   
crosstab(
'select dist_name::text "District Name", service_name::text "Service Name", status ,count 
from mpr_application_status ORDER BY 1,2',
'select ''APPROVED'' union select ''PENDING'' union select ''REJECTED'' ') 
AS ct ("District Name" text, "Service Name" text,"Approved Count" bigint,"Pending Count" bigint, "Reject Count" bigint);
```

You can do it using `filter` clause also

```
select 
dist_name,
service_name,
sum("count") filter (where status='Approved') "Approved Count",
sum("count") filter (where status='Pending') "Pending Count",
sum("count") filter (where status='Rejected') "Rejected Count",
sum("count")

from mpr_application_status
group by 1,2
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e63bee25edf777cb5e04d9d7814de5be)

Comment: ERROR:  invalid return type
DETAIL:  Query-specified return tuple has 5 columns but crosstab returns 4.
SQL state: 42601

Comment: @RajeevMassey Please read the note as i have mentioned use `'select ''APPROVED'' union select ''PENDING'' union select ''REJECTED'' '` in place of `'select distinct status from mpr_application_status order by 1'` because your sample data is not having `Rejected` data so current query is returning only 2 values Approved and Pending.

Comment: if any of the APPROVED, REJECTED OR PENDING is not present it should by default put 0

Comment: I have updated the answer as per note with DEMO and removed the note now check it.